# звук один раз при обновлении

Tags: javascript

Таблица на моем сайте обновляется, например, каждые 10 секунд, проверяя наличие новых записей через AJAX.

Сейчас, при появлении новой записи показывается фон в строке таблицы (выделяет её).

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы при первом показе воспроизводился звук (например, щелчок). Звук должен быть исключительно в первый раз при появлении нового блока; в последующих обновлениях не должно быть никаких звуковых сигналов.

Comment: Думал в таком направлении:
Сделать класс например audioStop и audioStart
После чего написать типа:
если класс = audioStop - то пропускаем, если класс равен audioStart - то воспроизводим звук и меняем класс на audioStop .
Но в js не силен - подскажите если правильно как это описать

Comment: Просто один булевский флаг. Если `true` то звук не воспроизводим, если `false`, то воспроизводим и меняем на `true`

Answer (score 0):

С помощью **MutationObserver()**; можно отслеживать изменения HTML-кода. (В данном случае появился новый ряд в таблице.)

```js
var target = document.getElementById('some-id');
 
// создаём экземпляр MutationObserver
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
 audio.play();
  });    
});
 
// конфигурация нашего observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
 
// передаём в качестве аргументов целевой элемент и его конфигурацию
observer.observe(target, config);
 
// по желанию позже можно остановить наблюдение
observer.disconnect();

setTimeout(function() {
 element.setAttribute('data-text', 'whatever');
 target.innerHTML=target.innerHTML;
}, 10000);
```

```html
<div id="some-id"></div>
<audio id=audio src="sound.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: в таймере element чему равен?

Comment: Сейчас выясню...

Comment: Перепишите содержимое setTimeout() так: target.innerHTML='whatever';